# In d3.js, while importing csv files using a row conversion, how can I "slice" the data to only include a range of rows?

Tags: csv, d3.js, import

I am working in d3 with a data table including over 39000 rows, and I do not want to visually represent all items at once. This is what I have currently:

```
 var impt = d3.csv("Data/prisoncsv8.csv", function(data, i) {
        return {
            //more data here in the following format
            "id": i,
            "stage": 1,
            "columntitle": data.columntitle
        }

    }).then(function(data, i) {

        svg.selectAll('circle')
            .data(data)
            .join('circle')
            .attr('r', 1)
            .attr('fill', 'gray')
            .attr('cx',function(dat) {
                return Math.random()*500
            })
            .attr('cy', function(dat) {
                return Math.random()*500
            })
    })
```

I hope to be able to specify as variables a start and end index and have only those rows mapped.

I have already tried things such as .slice on the data, but that doesn't work of course because function(data){} works one row at a time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#csv) internally uses `d3.csvParse()`—which itself is only a tiny wrapper around [`d3.dsvParse()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#dsv)—for parsing the rows of the fetched file. The docs on the latter method have got you covered:

> If the returned value is null or undefined, the row is skipped and will be omitted from the array returned by *dsv*.parse; otherwise, the returned value defines the corresponding row object.

For your code this could be something along the following lines:

```
var impt = d3.csv("Data/prisoncsv8.csv", function(data, i) {
  return i < datastart || i > dataend
    ? null   // Skip lines outside the range [datastart, dataend].
    : {      // Normal conversion for all lines to included.
      //more data here in the following format
      "id": i,
      "stage": 1,
      "columntitle": data.columntitle
    };
}).then(function(data, i) {
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution that might work, apply slice directly in nodes. I am still a little worried that indexes might mismatch or something.

```
...
}).then(function(data, i) {
    svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(data.slice(datastart,dataend))
...
```