# How to append circles selectively?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have the following snippet where I am trying to append circles to the bubble chart. However, due to the nature of the data file, there may be false values like `0` or `NaN` in *GDPperCapita* and/or *LifeExpectancy*.

I am wondering if there is a way I can skip appending a certain circle if the x or y coordinate is 0.

```
var dots = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.GDPperCapita); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.LifeExpectancy); } )
      .attr("r", function (d) { return z(d.Population); } )
      .style("fill", function (d) { return myColor(d.BirthRate); } )
      .style("opacity", "0.7")
      .attr("stroke", "white")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter.

This can be done filtering the data array (here, `Array.prototype.filter`) or filtering the selection (here, `selection.filter`). Do not confuse `Array.prototype.filter` with `selection.filter`, they look quite similar in the examples below but they are very different things.

For filtering your data:

```
var dots = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data.filter(function(d){
        return d.GDPperCapita && d.LifeExpectancy
    }))
    //etc...
```

For filtering your selection:

```
var dots = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .filter(function(d){
        return d.GDPperCapita && d.LifeExpectancy
    })
    //etc...
```

Which one you should use depends on some details that you didn't share.

Also, if you'll never ever use those values in the dataviz you can also get rid of them in the *row function*, assuming you are using `d3.csv` or any other `d3.dsv` variant (row functions are not available in `d3.json`). Something like this:

```
d3.csv("foo.csv", function(d){
    if (d.GDPperCapita && d.LifeExpectancy) return d;
}).then(
    //etc...
```

Or returning `null`, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052738/5768908):

```
d3.csv("foo.csv", function(d){
    return d.GDPperCapita && d.LifeExpectancy ? d : null;
}).then(
    //etc...
```

In my opinion using a row function is by far the best option.

Comment: Exactly! IMO, do filter as early as possible for performance reasons and to keep a low memory footprint! This clearly dictates the following order of choice: 1. while loading in row function (good); 2. filtering data array before binding (neutral); 3. filtering the selection as a last resort (usually bad). When large datasets are involved its the increasing number of loops down the mentioned order which really does hurt.